# javascript/jquery syntax differences, declaring new a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

My code in javascript causes an error at the following line:

```js
var tries:int=GetCallAttemptCount();
```

The error message says *Error in Script Unexpected token : , Line 3*

Line 3 is where the error appears.  The script was originally in jquery, so I wonder is there a difference in how a variable is declared in Javascript and Jquery?

I'm computer literate, but I am a beginner with Javascript.

Thanks all, Adam

Comment: replace `:` with `,`

Comment: That looks like TypeScript, try `var tries=GetCallAttemptCount();`

Comment: JQuery is JavaScript, the syntax is identical. Your code looks like TypeScript though. Remove `:int` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: What is :int ? You are trying to give a type to var tries using : but that's a typescript syntax. Can't use that in Javascript or jQuery for that matter

Comment: Javascript is loosely typed you don't need to define the type you need to study a lot first

Comment: declaring var types in javascript doesn't exist, it exists in TypeScript though, but differently: `var tries:number=GetCallAttemptCount();`, not `int` (note: typescript must be compiled to run as javascript)

Comment: I tried var tries,int=GetCallAttemptCount(); - it SEEMS to work, but I will need to test the whole thing to make sure.  
Thanks all!

Comment: @Adam That sets a variable named `int` to the result of the function, and leaves `tries` undefined, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @mplungjan, gurvinder372, Mike McCaughan, freedomn-m, Shiladitya

thanks for explaining.  I'll try and keep complete code examples that can be run, in this case I was trying to be concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not javascript, this looks like typescript, in JS:

```
var tries = GetCallAttemptCount();
```